# Linux Fedora: can I preserve what I am doing so that everything will be restored when I power up again

Tags: linux, hibernate, sleep

I have Linux Fedora 20, with Gnome classic desktop. When I power down, via the "Power Down" icon on the top bar, everything shuts down, and everything is gone when I power up again, although I can recover web pages using History in my browser. I would like, if I choose, to have the session restored totally and exactly to the situation when I powered off. Please is this possible, e.g by suspending or sleeping the machine? I cannot find anything already there to do this.

I think that `acpi` maybe the answer, but I have read that this may clash with Gnome actions, and I have no `/etc/acpi/handler.sh` file on my system, so I presume that `acpi` is not installed.. I am reluctant to try `acpi` until I know how to do so safely.

I would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: As root in a terminal emulator `systemctl hibernate` should do the trick. You can use `systemctl hybrid-sleep` to make both suspend types(ram and disk) and use the one that is available to resume.

Comment: Good try, @nwilder. I tried `systemctl hibernate`, but it crashed the machine, partially recovered somehow with a lot of what had been there, but some things I could not access. Powered off and on again the normal way, now ok again as the usual start up.

Comment: Follow up to my last comment. I had spotted a message that fleetingly said "not enough space, and I really did have a lot of browser windows and tabs open. Tried it again with less on the screen and worked fine. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it, thanks.

Comment: Your swap partition have the size equals or larger than your ram?
 It´s needed for hibernation purpouses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As root user, and since Fedora 20 uses `systemd` the more appropiated way to do this is through the `hibernate` target:

```
systemctl hibernate
```

If you want to do this as normal user, you could use sudo and add the following line on `/etc/sudoers` through the `visudo` command:

```
user hostname =NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl hibernate
```

Other solution to allow hibernate with a normal user involves some thinkering with [PolKit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit).

To work without further problems, i suggest you to have at [least the same size of swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) that you have in RAM(look at hibernation - Fedora uses the same method).